# (Cucumber Rails) Capybara: within(selector) should persist after call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, cucumber, capybara

I have a page and I want several items within several other items. So basically my feature could look like this:

```
Scenario: Footer has caption Impressum
  Given I am on the index page.
  When I look at the footer
  Then I should see a caption "Impressum"
```

What I would wish to work is this:

```
When /I look at the footer/ do
  scope("footer") # << css selector <footer\b.*</footer>
end

Then /I should see a caption "(.*?)"/ do |caption|
  within "h3" do
    page.should have_content(caption)
  end
end
```

How could I go with implementing this as solid as possible?

To go into more detail, a page that should pass is this:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<footer>
<h3>Impressum</h3>
<p>Address: Baker Street 21</p>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

While a page that should **not** pass is this:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<h3>Impressum</h3>
<footer><p>Address: Baker Street 21</p></footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I would do:

```
When /I look at the footer/ do
  # save a scope that should be used in a 'within' block
  @scope = "footer" # << css selector <footer\b.*</footer>
end

Then /I should see a caption "(.*?)"/ do |caption|
  # use the scope set above, or don't if it's not set
  within "#{@scope || ''} h3" do
    page.should have_content(caption)
  end
end
```

Comment: This is what my first attempt looked like, the problem with this approach though is that I'd have to put that `within` boilerplate before **each** and **every** `Then` block. The solid way would also be `@scope << "footer"` and let `@scope` be an array that gets initialized in a `Before` and in the `Then` you'd write: `within @scope.push("h3").join(" ") { ... }` This is probably what I will fall back to if I can't find a more solid solution.

Comment: By using `@scope || ''` you can allow `@scope` to be unset, which means you don't have to set it before every `Then` block.  You can certainly get fancier with it if you want.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to use a helper

```
# features/support/scope_helper.rb
module ScopeHelper
  def scope sel = nil
    @scope = sel if sel
    within @scope, &Proc.new if block_given?
  end
end
World(ScopeHelper)
```

Then, I use it like that:

```
When /^I look at the footer$/ do
  scope 'footer'
end

Then /^I should see a caption "(.*)"$/ do |caption|
  scope{ find('h3').should have_content(caption) }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar challenge with such dependencies. In my case I have a table and would like to click on a delete link of a specific row. I could not find a proper solution so I decided to do it in one sentence:

```
When I search for the row containing «Beverly C. Crusher» and click on «Delete Task»
```